# CUDA Nsight Debug Focus, Visual Studio 2012 Edition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cuda, nsight

I'm working on a project that includes working with Visual Studio 2012 and CUDA Development and integrated is the Nsight Debugging environment to it. I can very easily see threads on GPU up to threadIdx == 128, however, when I try to see threads with higher index, meaning that blocks other than the first block, using debugging focus dialog box reached through CUDA Debug focus, I am having difficulty, switching to other blocks. Is this normal operation of Nsight or not, any answers would be appreciated. Thanks all.

Comment: What is `threadIdx`  you a referring to? Do you mean the built-in CUDA variable (ie `threadIdx.{xyz}`? What is the block size you are running?

Comment: I was referring to Cuda built-in threadIdx.x variable.

Comment: Well then your question makes no sense. ThreadIdx is a block scope variable. It has the same range of values in every block. There are no "threads with higher index, meaning that blocks other than the first block"

Comment: Yes, of course you're right, I should ask the question in a more elegant way. In fact, I was wondering if I can see blocks with (blockIdx.x != 0). But, anyway I have found a way and posted my method below.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to see blocks with index higher than zero, what you just need to do is to set all the breakpoints in the cuda program as conditional and then start the Nsight debugging environment. It then shows other blocks as well. However, I think that is also related to the number of streaming multiprocessors residing on the GPU. According to my knowledge, number of streaming multiprocessors is equal to the number of blocks that can run simultaneously at the same time. I have been using for some time GeForce GT630 and that have only single streaming multiprocessor which is why I'm seeing only the first block running but not the others. However, debugging is still so slow.

Comment: Thats correct.  conditional breakpoints are the way to go.  When stopped at a breakpoint, you can only switch focus to a thread/block that is currently resident/executing on the GPU.  For a kernel with a large complement of blocks, many will not be accessible at any given time via focus-switching.  You need to use conditional breakpoints so the block in question is actually resident.  Depending on the specifics of your code and the conditional breakpoint, it can be much slower than an ordinary breakpoint.

Comment: Considering that even non-conditional breakpoints are slow, no one would dare to resort to conditional breakpoints. There should be a smarter way Nvidia should focus on for its later CUDA versions. Thanks Robert.

Answer (score 0):

Hi switching blocks is a common operation in Nisght, please follow these steps

1. Launch your cuda app and wait until one bp is hit.
2. Open the "CUDA Info" windows via "Visual studio -> Nsight -> Windows -> Cuda Info"
3. Switch the page to block, you can see all the launched blocks in current app.
4. Double click each line and you can switch to another block.
5. You can do the same operation for warp and thread

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried what you said above and see that there is only single line meaning that only the first block is seen and others are gone or missing. Is there any method that I do not know yet that enables Visual Studio to launch other blocks as well?